# How to determine a single property difference between two types?

Tags: f#, comparison

I have been looking for a more concise way to code this (below). Basically, I need a way to determine if only one of a set of properties does not equal its counterpart on a different type (`address` and `alternateAddress` are different types). If only ONE of the 5 values is doesn't match then I want a specific error, otherwise I want a more general error.

Note the `==` and `!=` are custom infix operators we have for case-insensitive comparisons.

```
   open System

   type Errors =
   | InvalidStreet
   | InvalidCity
   | InvalidState
   | InvalidPostalCode
   | InvalidCountry
   | InvalidAddress

   type Address =
       {
           Street: string
           City: string
           Region: string
           PostalCode: string
           Country: string
       }

   type AlternateAddress =
       {
           Street: string
           City: string
           Region: string
           PostalCode: string
           Country: string
       }

   let inline (==) (s1: string) (s2: string) = s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
   let inline (!=) s1 s2 = s1 == s2 |> not

   let address = {Address.Street = "123 Main St."; City = "Happytown"; Region = "CA"; PostalCode = "90210"; Country = "USA"}
   let alternateAddress = Some {AlternateAddress.Street = "123 Main"; City = "Happytown"; Region = "CA"; PostalCode = "90210"; Country = "USA"}

   match alternateAddress with
   | Some alternateAddress ->
       if
              address.Street      != alternateAddress.Street
           && address.City        == alternateAddress.City
           && address.Region      == alternateAddress.Region
           && address.PostalCode  == alternateAddress.PostalCode
           && address.Country     == alternateAddress.Country
       then InvalidStreet
       elif
              address.Street      == alternateAddress.Street
           && address.City        != alternateAddress.City
           && address.Region      == alternateAddress.Region
           && address.PostalCode  == alternateAddress.PostalCode
           && address.Country     == alternateAddress.Country
       then InvalidCity
       elif
              address.Street       == alternateAddress.Street
           && address.City         == alternateAddress.City
           && address.Region       != alternateAddress.Region
           && address.PostalCode   == alternateAddress.PostalCode
           && address.Country      == alternateAddress.Country
       then InvalidState
       elif
              address.Street       == alternateAddress.Street
           && address.City         == alternateAddress.City
           && address.Region       == alternateAddress.Region
           && address.PostalCode   != alternateAddress.PostalCode
           && address.Country      == alternateAddress.Country
       then InvalidPostalCode
       elif
              address.Street       == alternateAddress.Street
           && address.City         == alternateAddress.City
           && address.Region       == alternateAddress.Region
           && address.PostalCode   == alternateAddress.PostalCode
           && address.Country      != alternateAddress.Country
       then InvalidCountry
       else InvalidAddress
   | _ -> InvalidAddress
```

Comment: Why are you creating two records with basically the same fields? You get structural equality by default. Compare two set of records and if there's a mismatch, then match on it.

Comment: This is a simplified example that I am using for illustration.  In my actual code the `Address` is a record type using Single Case Unions and the `AlternateAddress` type is a third party schema that uses primitive types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to define a list of corresponding "getters" (functions that take one of your records and return a string) for each of the fields together with associated error. For simplicity, I made `alternateAddress` non-optional:

```
let comparers : ((Address -> _) * (AlternateAddress -> _) * _) list = 
  [ (fun x -> x.Street), (fun x -> x.Street), InvalidStreet;
    (fun x -> x.City), (fun x -> x.City), InvalidStreet 
    (fun x -> x.Region), (fun x -> x.Region), InvalidStreet 
    (fun x -> x.PostalCode), (fun x -> x.PostalCode), InvalidStreet 
    (fun x -> x.Country), (fun x -> x.Country), InvalidStreet ]
```

Now, you can iterate over `comparers` and use the first function to get a field from `Address`, second function to get a field from `AlternateAddress` and if they do not match, return the third element of the tuple, which is the error to report.

You can use `List.choose` to get a list that is empty when all fields match and, otherwise, contains a list of errors when there were mismatching fields:

```
let errors = comparers |> List.choose (fun (getAddr, getAlt, err) ->
  if getAddr address != getAlt alternateAddress then Some err else None)
```

The `errors` list will be empty if there are no issues, contain one error if there was just one error or contain multiple errors:

```
match errors with
| [] -> printfn "All good!"
| [err] -> printfn "One error: %A" err
| _ -> printfn "Multiple errors!"
```

It is worth noting that depending on your particular situation, it might perhaps be a good idea to restructure the code to make this operation easier - but it's hard to say without knowing more about your situation.

Comment: Goddamnit, Tomas; *seconds* before I could post the exact same thing. Was that really necessary? :P

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Haha, sorry! This happens to me too, more often than I'd want! :-)

Comment: This works perfectly and make my code much more succinct.  Thank you!